# How can i display seconds ago/minutes ago/with unix timestamp?

Tags: php, unix, time

I need the unix timestamp - the timestamp i have. Then display the time between like on twitter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the difference called diff:

```
$seconds = intval($diff) % 60;
$minutes = intval($diff/60) % 60;
$hours = intval($diff/3600) % 24;
$days = intval($diff/(3600*24));
```

Is this what you want ?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what language you need it, but if it will end up in a web page, you may try [`timeago`](http://timeago.yarp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

#### Use example :

```php
echo time_elapsed_string('@1367367755');
echo time_elapsed_string('@1367367755', true);
```

#### Output :

```
4 months ago
4 months, 2 weeks, 3 days, 1 hour, 49 minutes, 15 seconds ago
```

**[Link to the function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/67332)**