# PHP: How to echo remaining time in minutes from microtime

Tags: php, microtime

The following shows time in seconds, and want it in minutes, how do i convert to minutes?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ip = '$ip' AND mtime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE ORDER by mtime DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $diff = microtime(true) - $row['mtime']; //here the time difference between last sended message and this try
    $remaining = (5*60 - (int) $diff);
   echo $remaining;
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: divide by 60. `$diff_min = $diff/60;` http://bit.ly/18cPxDk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220387/how-to-count-seconds-into-minutes-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are sixty (60) seconds in one (1) minute. To convert seconds to minutes, simply divide the amount of seconds by sixty (60).

```
$tstart = (string) microtime(true); // casting to string shows type doesn't matter
sleep(3); // for variance
$tstop = microtime(true);
$diffSeconds = round($tstop-$tstart);
$diffMinutes = ceil($diffSeconds/60); // here is the division

echo $diffSeconds.'second'.($diffSeconds==1?'':'s')."\n"; // assuming plain text out
echo $diffMinutes.'minute'.($diffMinutes==1?'':'s')."\n";
```

Outputs:

> in seconds: 3.0001471042633
>
> in minutes: 0.050002451737722

Comment: i don't want those numbers after the decimal, i just wanna echo real time to a normal user not a programmer.

Comment: @Eustatia try rounding with [round](http://php.net/round), [ceil](http://php.net/ceil) or [floor](http://php.net/floor).

Comment: @Eustatia well? any luck?