# PHP Time Since Function?

Tags: php, function, date, time

I'm looking for a function that will take in a unix timestamp and output something like this:

4 years, 3 months, 12 days, 4 hours and 23 minutes ago.

Everything I have found has been pretty dates that just say something similar to "5 years ago" which I don't want.

Comment: @Patrick: Not truly duplicate. Over there there is no implementation except for pointing out to some urls :)

Answer (score 23):

You want [`DateInterval`'s format method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php):

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($timestamp);
$interval = $date->diff(new \DateTime('now'));
echo $interval->format('%y years, %m months, %d days, %h hours and %i minutes ago');
```

Comment: I really wish people would use the DateTime objects more, I hate seeing all the second manipulations.

Comment: Is this only available in php 5.3+ ?

Comment: @Wes: yes, according to php.net.

Comment: Thanks, this seems the smartest way to go but I would like to be able to support at least 5.2

Comment: @Wes - fair enough. Although a friendly reminder that php ended 5.2 support December 2010 ;)

Comment: If we only lived in such a world :)

Comment: what's the backslash for in front of DateTime ?

Comment: @DavidBeckwith - to ensure you are using the `DateTime` from the global namespace. Probably unnecessary.

Comment: @rojoca ah ok thank you!

Comment: How would you output only the largest unit? ie.. 10 hours ago,  or 3 months ago, but not the whole string of every single interval.

Comment: @sxflynn you should check the docs for DateInterval http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php - there are properties for each unit e.g. `$interval->y`