# format datetime(0000-00-00 00:00:00 ) to 00:00:00 with time remaing

Tags: php, datetime, time, timer, string-formatting

I have a `$time` variable set some time in the future. In this format `2011-02-15 23:19:44`. Now I need to set time remaining in this format `00:00:10`.

If for example the $time is 1 hour, 3 minutes and 10 sec in the future. The format would be `01:03:10`

Comment: and if its +24 hrs difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at using the DateTime and DateInterval classes.

```
$futureDate = new DateTime($time);
$currentDate = new DateTime();

$dateDiff = $currentDate->diff($futureDate);

echo $dateDiff->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Note: if the difference is more than 24 hours, then you should look at the %Y-%m-%d values or %a for total days.

If you wanted to show any additional days as multiples of 24 hours then:

```
printf('%d:%s', 
    $dateDiff->format('%a') * 24 + $dateDiff->format('%H'), 
    $dateDiff->format('%I:%S')
);
```

Comment: ('%H:%I:%S') ?  to get the leading '0' on minutes and seconds?

Comment: @jpwco thanks, I'm too used to the regular datetime formats :D

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same problem as discussed here: [PHP Time Since Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010016/php-time-since-function)

You're wanting to compare a future timestamp against the current time... the solutions in the linked question will also apply to this one.