# PHP Time to Relative Time

Tags: php, mysql, math, datetime, time

I am trying to convert my already-implemented date format of:

```
$dateEntered = date('mdY');
```

To a relative time using this function:

```
function RelativeTime($dateEntered)
```

Now, the actual script that runs all of this looks like:

```
<?php

function RelativeTime($dateEntered){
    $difference = time() - $dateEntered;
    $periods = array("sec", "min", "hour", "day", "week",
        "month", "years", "decade");
    $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

    if ($difference > 0) { // this was in the past
        $ending = "ago";
    } else { // this was in the future
        $difference = -$difference;
        $ending = "to go";
    }
    for($j = 0; array_key_exists($j,$lengths)&&$difference >= $lengths[$j]; $j++) {
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
        $difference = round($difference);
        if($difference != 1) $periods[$j].= "s";
        $text = "$difference $periods[$j] $ending";
        return $text;
    }
}

// Check Service Call Status & Mail if found Unpaid    
$query = "SELECT id, account, status, dateEntered FROM service WHERE status = 'Unpaid'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    $account = $row[1];
    $status = $row[2];
    $dateEntered = $row[3];

    $timeToSend = RelativeTime(strtotime($dateEntered));

    // mailStatusUpdate($account, $status, $timeToSend);
}

?>
```

If I run the script, I get a return of "4 decades ago".

I have my service table with one record in it. The $dateEntered variable returns:

```
01302012
```

This is shown in the `print_r` output below.  I basically want this to say "x days ago" or whatever the increment is.

Instead of returning the correct information (such as x days ago), it returns:

```
 4 decades ago
```

Obviously this is wrong. Here is a print row so you see what I am working with:

```
Array ( [0] => 26 [1] => Example Client [2] => Unpaid [3] => 01302012 ) 1
```

(I don't know what that "`1`" at the end is, though.)

Comment: returning from inside a `for` loop looks kinda strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your `strtotime()` usage is getting a correct `timestamp` from your original `$dateEntered` value?

Particularly on this line: `$timeToSend = RelativeTime(strtotime($dateEntered));`

**Edit:**

You also might try converting the original date format that you had into something like YYYY-MM-DD for `strtotime()`, like this:

```
$dateEntered = substr($dateEntered, 4,4) . '-' . substr($dateEntered, 0, 2) . '-' . substr($dateEntered, 2,2);
```

This takes the original format: `01302012` and puts it into this format: `2012-01-30`.  Then, you could use `strtotime()` like this:

```
strtotime($dateEntered);
```

Comment: My $dateEntered variable gives: 01302012. I need to convert this to the equivalent unix timestamp. If i try to echo $timeToSend I get a "4 decades ago"

Comment: I updated my answer to include one possible way to change your `01302012` format into `2012-01-30`.  Maybe that will work for you?

Answer (score 0):

#### Use example :

```php
echo time_elapsed_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35');
echo time_elapsed_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35', true);
```

#### Output :

```
4 months ago
4 months, 2 weeks, 3 days, 1 hour, 49 minutes, 15 seconds ago
```

**[Link to the function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/67332)**

<sup>If you wish to add support for decades, it can be simply implemented like weeks.</sup>