# Find out how long ago something happened

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I've got a webpage which records in UNIX when it was last viewed into a datbase field.
I want to pull off a report incuding how many days ago this page was last viewed.  I'm doing this in PHP

How do i work this out to display?  At the moment I have the field showing when it was last accessed by using gmdate("M D Y ", $UNIXTIMESTAMPFIELD) but instead of the date of last access I want to display something like

23 days ago

Thanks

Kieran

Comment: [`strtotime()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) as answered on [Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago) looks like it might do what you want

Comment: You can subtract this date-time value from the now-moment (`date()`) and divide it by 60 to get the minutes, 60*60 to get hours, 24*60*60 to get days and so on.

Comment: @Voitcus, seconds based calculations will trip you up on daytime savings and other quirks of the calendar system, its really a bad idea.

Comment: @complex857: you just took the words straight out of my mouth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty easy if you're on PHP5.3 or later. Use the `DateInterval` object, which can understand unix timestamps and easily output a difference.

What you can do is very, very straightforward. Assume your timestamps are $TS1, $TS2.

Step 1: create the `DateTime` objects for each:

```
$DT1 = new DateTime("@{$TS1}");
$DT2 = new DateTime("@{$TS2}");
```

Step 2: diff them

```
$diff = $DT1->diff($DT2);
```

Step 3: print stuff!

```
echo "Days: ".$diff->d;
```

This automatically takes into account timezone settings, amongst other things. It also allows you to easily substract from datetime objects should you need to.

Comment: Good answer. But note that you'll have to use `DateTime::setTimestamp()` to initialize the DateTime object if you are working with UNIX timestamps. You cannot pass them to the constructor

Comment: @hek2mgl actually, you can, if you prepend the timestamp with `@` See the [note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) for `timezone` in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for this information! unfortunately can only upvote once ;)

Answer (score 0):

Difference is clearly `$diff = time() -  $UNIXTIMESTAMPFIELD` (now-event). Not you just have to format it correctly:

```php
function time_diff_to_human($seconds){
    // For seconds
    if( $seconds < 60){
        if( $seconds == 1){
            return "a second ago"
        }
        return sprintf( "%d seconds ago", $seconds);
    }

    // Minutes
    $minutes = round( $seconds/60);
    if( $minutes < 60){
        if( $minutes == 1){
            return "a minute ago"
        }
        return sprintf( "%d minutes ago", $minutes);
    }

    // Hours
    $hours = round( $minutes/60);
    if( $hours < 24){
        if( $hours == 1){
            return "last hour"
        }
        return sprintf( "%d hours", $hours);
    }

    // Add some formatting to days
    $days = $months/24;
    if( $days < 31){
        if( $days == 1){
            return 'yesterday';
        }
        return sprintf( "%d days", $days);
    }

    // Approx months
    $months = round( $days/30);
    if( $months < 12){
        if( $months == 1){
            return "last month"
        }
        return sprintf( "%d months", $months);
    }

    // And finally years, note that they are calculated from days
    $years = round( $days/365.4);
    if( $years == 1){
        return "last year"
    }
    return sprintf( "%d years", $years);

}
```