# Change time to timestamp?

Tags: php, timestamp

i'm looking for a PHP code to change time like this: `Fri Jul 16 16:58:46 +0000 2010` to a timestamp like this: `20 secs ago`

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function and then compare it to the current time:

```
$timestamp = strtotime( 'Fri Jul 16 16:58:46 +0000 2010' );

$diff = time() - $timestamp;
```

This gives you the difference to the current time and you can output it in the way you need.

Comment: only after a while, you might see `2817646532 seconds ago`. a more robust library is needed I believe.

Comment: @SagiIsha I left out the output part on purpose :-) But you're right, one has to put some thought to that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try with **strtotime** like

```
$my_time = strtotime('Fri Jul 16 16:58:46 +0000 2010');
$diff = time() - $my_time;
echo $diff." Seconds ago..";
```

you can get the minutes and hours as well like

```
echo $diff/60."Minutes Ago";
echo $diff/(60*60)."Hours Ago";
```

Totally you can use

```
$a = array( 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'year',
            30 * 24 * 60 * 60       =>  'month',
            24 * 60 * 60            =>  'day',
            60 * 60                 =>  'hour',
            60                      =>  'minute',
            1                       =>  'second'
            );

foreach ($a as $secs => $str) {
    $d = $diff / $secs;
    if ($d >= 1) {
        $r = round($d);
        echo $r . ' ' . $str . ($r > 1 ? 's' : '').' ago..';
    }
}
```

Comment: Try my edit also...my third ans will help you more

Answer (score 1):

You should use a robust library to handle this, so you can estimate not only seconds but hours, days, weeks, months etc, when the time elapses as long. See i.e http://github.com/jimmiw/php-time-ago

Comment: or you could use the built-in DateTime and DateInterval classes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php