# Reverse string to time

Tags: php, html, timestamp

I have a time currently displaying like this:

```
Thu Sep 12 04:28:37 +0000 2013
```

I know that with PHP's strtotime you can input things like '2 days ago' or 'last week', but what I want to do is input the timestamp I already have, and output something like '3 hours ago' or '1 day ago' in my HTML.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build in way. check out this post: [Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago)

use it like `time_elapsed_string(strtotime("Thu Sep 12 04:28:37 +0000 2013"))`

Comment: Ah cool thanks! Yeh that looks like the sorta thing I need. Shame it's not a build in function though when it can do it the other way round.