# Converting this date into time ago

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

Looking for a lightweight function that would convert this date as it is displayed "**Thu Sep 19 08:43:29 +0000 2013**"

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to provide more information than this. For example: What format do you want the "time ago" in? What have you attempted so far to achieve this? (StackOverflow isn't here to do you work for you.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Time ago function**

```
function time_ago($date) {
    if (empty($date)) {
        return "No date provided";
    }
    $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
    $lengths = array("60", "60", "24", "7", "4.35", "12", "10");
    $now = time();
    $unix_date = strtotime($date);
// check validity of date
    if (empty($unix_date)) {
        return "Bad date";
    }
// is it future date or past date
    if ($now > $unix_date) {
        $difference = $now - $unix_date;
        $tense = "ago";
    } else {
        $difference = $unix_date - $now;
        $tense = "from now";
    }
    for ($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths) - 1; $j++) {
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    }
    $difference = round($difference);
    if ($difference != 1) {
        $periods[$j].= "s";
    }
    return "$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";
}
```

To use this function, simply call:

```
<?php echo time_ago($mydate); ?>
```

[source](http://www.phpdevtips.com/2011/06/the-php-time-ago-function/)

Comment: If you're going to lift code from an external source (http://www.phpdevtips.com/2011/06/the-php-time-ago-function/) at least credit that source.

Comment: thanks for reminding me . i already did.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the handy DateTime class :

```
$oDate = new DateTime('Thu Sep 19 08:43:29 +0000 2013');
$oNow = new DateTime();
$oInterval = $oDate->diff($oNow);
echo $oInterval->format('%R%a days');
```

This will display the difference between now and the date, in days :

> +0 days

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use example :

```php
echo time_elapsed_string('Thu Sep 19 08:43:29 +0000 2013');
echo time_elapsed_string('Thu Sep 19 08:43:29 +0000 2013', true);
```

#### Output :

```
1 hour ago
1 hour, 35 minutes, 7 seconds ago
```

**[Link to the function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/67332)**