# PHP - subtracting time return nothing

Tags: php, time, strtotime

I found a function form SC to output human readable time. like `

> 5 hours, 1 hour, 5 years, etc

```
function human_time ($time)
{

    $time = time() - strtotime($time); // to get the time since that moment
    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }

}
```

And I have time as string: `2013-09-28 20:55:42`

when I call this function `human_time('2013-09-28 20:55:42')`

then it return nothing, why ?
I have added `strtotime` in above function.

Please tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Have you considered using php's `DateTime` class for your purpose? I guess there's no need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: I tried to search on google, and I found this function on stackoverflow, please suggest if there is already a function

Comment: Is this of any use to you? https://github.com/vascowhite/TimeAgo it will at least show you one way of doing it.

Comment: Take a look at [this simple function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/67332).

Answer (score 1):

This is no ready-to-use code, but rather supposed to guide you the right way:

```
$then = new DateTime($time); // you might need to format $time using strtotime or other functions depending on the format provided
$now = new DateTime();
$diff = $then->diff($now, true);
echo $diff->format('Your style goes here');
```

See [DateTime Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for further documentation or feel free to ask here.

Edit: Link fixed.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use example :

```php
echo time_elapsed_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35');
echo time_elapsed_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35', true);
```

#### Output :

```
4 months ago
4 months, 2 weeks, 3 days, 1 hour, 49 minutes, 15 seconds ago
```

**[Link to the function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/67332)**