# Covert my date to hours and days

Tags: php, date, datetime

Hi i need covert date to hours and days

My date format is like this : 2013-09-01 22:15:59

I need to show like this within 24 hours (hours) :**(12 hours back)**

I need to show like this after 24 hours (days)  :**(5 days back)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/67332)

Answer (score 2):

#### Use example :

```php
echo time_elapsed_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35');
echo time_elapsed_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35', true);
```

#### Output :

```
4 months ago
4 months, 2 weeks, 3 days, 1 hour, 49 minutes, 15 seconds ago
```

**[Link to the function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/67332)**