# conerting date('d-m-Y H:i in php to ago

Tags: php, time, converters

I have a code

```
echo date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($posts_row['post_date'])) . '</td></tr>';
```

The result:

```
23-10-2013 16:28
```

Is there a way to change into like:

```
Posted 12 minutes ago
```

or / &

```
Just Posted
```

Whats the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: How about subtracting current time with the "post date"? Try !

Comment: I'm a php noob... Please help. I can subtract numbers but when it comes to time.... i won't get it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago/18602474#18602474

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will help you to convert the date and make operations over it.

```
function elapsedTimeAgo ($newTime) {

$timeCalc = time() – strtotime($newTime);
$elapsedTimeText = "";

if ($timeCalc > (60*60*24)) {
    $elapsedTimeText = round($timeCalc/60/60/24) . "days ago";
} else if ($timeCalc > (60*60)) {
    $elapsedTimeText = round($timeCalc/60/60) . "hours ago";
} else if ($timeCalc > 60) {
    $elapsedTimeText = round($timeCalc/60) .  "minutes ago";
} else if ($timeCalc > 0) {
    $elapsedTimeText .=  "seconds ago";
} else {
    $elapsedTimeText .=  "Just Posted";
} 
return $elapsedTimeText;
}
```

echo elapsedTimeAgo($posts_row['post_date']);

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the difference of seconds between current time and posted time:

```
$number_of_seconds = strtotime("now") - strtotime($posts_row['post_date']);
```

Then, you can apply your logic to display how many seconds ago, just now, etc.