# How to display exact date difference in php

Tags: java, php, date

My Question is Little bit tricy . 
i have to display date difference. (i find out date difference in terms of 2 year 7 month 3 days 5 hrs 30 min.)

Now how i display upto exact 2 higher values 
please consider given case

case 1 : date difference is 0 year 2 month 21 days 7 hrs 30 min 
 output must be : 2 Month 21 days

case 2 : 0 year 0 month 0 days 7 hrs 20 min

 output must be : 7 hours 21 days

Comment: Do you have any code for how you are getting these dates? What are they held in?

Comment: What format are these dates in? Are they strings? Where is your code?

Comment: That's _rounded_. That's the _opposite of exact!_

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/67332 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/18863012/67332

Answer (score 0):

If your date differences is in the exact form as in your question (separated with " ") and formatted as strings. This will do the trick.

```
<?php
function display_times($string){
    $pieces = explode(" ",$string);

    $num_disp = 0;
    foreach($pieces as $i => $pice){
        if(is_numeric($pice) && intval($pice) != 0){
            echo $pice." ".$pieces[$i+1]." ";
            $num_disp++;
            if($num_disp >= 2) break;
        }
    }
}

$case1 = "0 year 2 month 21 days 7 hrs 30 min";
$case2 = "0 year 0 month 0 days 7 hrs 20 min";

display_times($case1);
echo PHP_EOL;
display_times($case2);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify **[this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18863012/67332)**. Replace 3rd parameter with `$depth` and modify array_slice line, like on [demo](https://eval.in/61856).

**Use examples :**

```
echo time_diff_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35', 'now', 1), "\n";
echo time_diff_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35', 'now', 2), "\n";
echo time_diff_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35', 'now', 3), "\n";
echo time_diff_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35', 'now', 4), "\n";
```

**Output :**

```
6 months ago
6 months, 6 days ago
6 months, 6 days, 12 hours ago
6 months, 6 days, 12 hours, 6 minutes ago
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/61856).**