# Write time left in a sentence with PHP - Plural, Singular, Conditional And

Tags: php, time

How would you write: hour(s) (and) minute(s) in a sentence? Is there a clean solution?

Like: There are **12hrs and 1min** left.

I have a $difference value to convert (seconds between two timestamps.)

Examples of desired output:

- 3hrs and 12mins
- 1hr and 1min
- 12hrs
- 43mins
- 1hr
- 1min

NOT:

- 3hrs and 1mins
- 1hrs and 0mins
- 0hrs and 0mins

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/67332)

Comment: I don't quite agree with this being a duplicate with the referenced, as this request is not dealing with past time, but rather future time. These two questions are specifically different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall assume you know how to convert a number of seconds into `$hours` and `$minutes`. From there:

```
$out = "";
if( $hours) $out .= $hours."hr";
if( $hours > 1) $out .= "s";
if( $hours && $minutes) $out .= " and ";
if( $minutes) $out .= $minutes."min";
if( $minutes > 1) $out .= "s";
if( !$out) $out = "now";
```