# TimeAgo - Year and Month ago

Tags: php, datetime

My unixtime is `1336608000`

which is exactly 2012-5-10.

1 year 10 months ago from today - 2014-03-06

Now what I want to do is output the year and month ago as it is. so I want to display:

`1 year 10 months ago.`

The most timeAgo functions I see here in Stackoverflow and all over the internet shows the time ago as "2 years ago" which is wrong. I have tried like 8-10 php functions to display the exact month count

So my question is, Is there a php time ago function that shows the exact year and month count instead of rounding it up?

Thanks

Comment: Since you don't seem to want to do the work yourself, this is a library/tool request, which is off-topic.

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I am not that good of a PHP developer.

Comment: That doesn't change what this site is and isn't for, I'm afraid. Please read the FAQ in future before posting, though you should know after almost 4 years that this is neither a library recommendation website, nor a code generator, nor a message board/forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this answer by Glavić](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago) and it works perfectly.

I tweaked it for you...

Usage: **echo time_elapsed_string('2012-5-10', true);**

```
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $string = array(
        'y' => 'year',
        'm' => 'month',
    );
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v;
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }

    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}
```