# PHP Date format and count time between 2 dates.

Tags: php, date, format

i have a date and want to count the time between now and the date.
ALso i want to return the time between the 2 dates in this example format:

4 weeks and 3 days ago.

Is this possible in PHP?

I hope you guys can help me!

Comment: Use date-diff : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date-diff.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/67332). Because he stated bellow in one of the comment `Thanks for the answers, but is it also possibile to make this dynamic ? Like this for example : 4 weeks and 3 days ago. 4 months and 3 weeks ago. 4 years and 2 months ago.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example :

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Will echo +2 days.

Source : http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 0):

**Determine the time(in seconds) between two dates :**

```
strtotime($human_readable_date);
```

**now subtract the time between two dates**

```
$seconds = strtotime1($date1) - strtotime1($date2);
```

**now get the actual time from these seconds**
you can get this time in your own format, just change the formatting type in this function

```
function formatSeconds( $seconds )
{
  $hours = 0;
  $milliseconds = str_replace( "0.", '', $seconds - floor( $seconds ) );

  if ( $seconds > 3600 )
  {
    $hours = floor( $seconds / 3600 );
  }
  $seconds = $seconds % 3600;


  return str_pad( $hours, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT )
       . gmdate( ':i:s', $seconds )
       . ($milliseconds ? ".$milliseconds" : '')
  ;
}
```

Comment: `strtotime()` doesn't return miliseconds, but it returns seconds from 1.1.1970....

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but is it also possibile to make this dynamic ?

Like this for example :

4 weeks and 3 days ago.
4 months and 3 weeks ago.
4 years and 2 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**date_diff()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) and a little math:

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$date = new DateTime('2014-05-01');

// Total difference in days
$total_days = date_diff($now, $date)->format('%a');

// Get weeks
$weeks = floor($total_days / 7);

// Get days
$days = $total_days % 7;

echo $weeks . ' weeks and ' . $days . ' days ago';
```

Output:

```
3 weeks and 5 days ago
```

Notes:

(1) `date_diff()` is valid in PHP v 5.3 and above.

(2) You may need to specifiy timezone using [DateTimeZone()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

[**SEE DEMO**](http://3v4l.org/PcXY0)

---

**OR, for PHP version < 5.3, use [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):**

```
$now = time();
$date = strtotime('2014-05-01');

$total_days = floor(($now - $date)/60/60/24);

$weeks = floor($total_days / 7);

$days = $total_days % 7;

echo $weeks . ' weeks and ' . $days . ' days ago';
```

Output:

```
3 weeks and 5 days ago
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://3v4l.org/GvO0b)

Comment: `%D` is not correct parameter for this solution... `%a` should be used, like @Kirito did in his answer.

Comment: @Glavić Oops, yes you're right, thanks. Answer updated.