# how to get a difference in dates, when the dates is passed through post variable to another page and echo the difference in php

Tags: php, date

I tried with the below code to find the difference between two dates which is passed through post variable and print, but failed.

`$fromdate=$_POST['from_date'];
        $todate=$_POST['to_date'];
        $date1 = new DateTime($fromdate); //inclusive
    $date2 = new DateTime($todate); //exclusive
    $diff = $date2->diff($date1);
    echo $diff;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/67332)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
<?php

    $_POST['from_date'] = "2014-10-01";
    $_POST['to_date'] = "2014-11-02";

    $fromdate = $_POST['from_date'];
    $todate = $_POST['to_date'];

    $diff = abs(strtotime($fromdate) - strtotime($todate));

    $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
    $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
    $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

    printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);

?>
```

Output:

```
0 years, 1 months, 2 days
```

Comment: it's a very unhelpful feature of all StackExchange sites. I can only say that it perfectly resembles the flaws of human society. Hope you have a thick skin..

Comment: Probably because not all years have 365 days, and not all months have 30 days.