# I want to create a script which tells me when a post is posted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook

I want to create a script in php, javascript or jquery which tells me when a post is posted like Facebook in facebook when we post a status it tells us posting time like 5 minute ago or so on. I have completed all other work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago

Comment: Thu shalt not code for the dark and evil facebook.

Comment: please do some research on your own before posting a question with very low quality on stackoverflow.

Comment: luschn, may be it is low quality for you but as a beginner I need some suggestion because I always want to do quality of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a coloumn to the table where you save the post details as `posted_at` and have `DATETIME` as its data type,

Use `$CurrentTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s" );` and insert while you create the post i.e., insert

So while retrieving the data just find the difference between the  posted time and current time by

```
$PostedTime = strtotime($FetchedData->posted_at) - strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s" ));
```

Then you shall convert the difference time as per your wish.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create function that will get one parameter "posted date" and it will calculate difference from today. it will generate string and return like "2 days ago/5 min ago" or date. it is depend on you.