# How to get days difference in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension

- how to get days diffrence from current day.
- tweetedAt: "2015-02-22 09:56:42".

twig

```
{% for key,value in data.about %}
{% set tweets_date=(value.tweetedAt|date).date("now").format('%a') %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have also tried

```
{% set dd='now'|date('d-m-Y') %}
{% set tweets_date=(value.tweetedAt|date).dd.format('%a') %}
```

Finally I tried but its giving error:

> A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{"

```
{% set difference = {{ date("m/d/Y") }}.diff(date(value.tweetedAt)) %}
{% set leftDays = difference.days %}
```

Error:

```
<span class="small light_grey">{{tweets_date}}</span>

Impossible to invoke a method ("date") on a string variable ("June 6, 2015 01:06") in AcmeBundle
```

- how to get diffrence from `tweet_date` in days ago form.

Updated my project installing `twig/extensions` via composer

```
user@intermsh-OptiPlex-380:~$ composer require twig/extensions
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "/usr/local/bin/composer self-update" to get the latest version.
Using version ~1.2 for twig/extensions
./composer.json has been updated
   Loading composer repositories with package information
   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
   - Installing twig/twig (v1.18.2)
   Downloading: 100%         

   - Installing twig/extensions (v1.2.0)
   Downloading: 100%         
   Downloading: 100%         

twig/extensions suggests installing symfony/translation (Allow the time_diff output to be translated)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Comment: Why not calculate it in the back-end? It would allow you much more flexibility and you can easily change it later without touching the template.

Comment: i think symfony cannot solved date diffrence

Comment: Well, you don't really need Symfony2's custom functionality here - you can do this with a pure PHP. Take a look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago

Comment: can you help in finding days diffrence

Comment: i have tweetedAt: "2015-02-22 09:56:42". date

Answer (score 15):

I tried this code and it works.

```
{% set difference = date(value.tweetedAt|date('Y/m/d')).diff(date('now'|date('Y/m/d'))) %}
{% set leftDays = difference.days %}
```

Answer (score 9):

You need use filters not methods on your objects. And you need to use `time_diff` filter:

```
{%set tweets_date=value.tweetedAt|time_diff %}
```

To make it work you need first install twig-extensions via composer:

```
composer require twig/extensions
```

and then include it in service container with appropriate tag:

```
services:
    app.twig.extension.date:
        class:        Twig_Extensions_Extension_Date
        tags:
             - { name: 'twig.extension' }
```

Comment: The filter "time_diff" does not exist in bundle error

Comment: i have reffer docs of symfony : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/date.html

Comment: when i use $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Date()); in controller it giving 503 error

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to register this extension in container.

Comment: still 503 error i done like :  acme.twig.acme_extension.date:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Date
        tags:
             - { name: 'twig.extension' }

Comment: i have use in service.yml services:
    acme.twig.acme_extension:
        class: Acme\biztradeshowsBundle\Twig\AcmeExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }

Comment: You need install it via composer. I again updated my answer. You can also implement your own filter and register it in container.

Comment: still 503 i have installer composer then also

Comment: Your error occurs from another place. I just tested my answer and it works. As I said before: if you can't configure twig-extensions you can create your own extension and use it.

Comment: Esque c'est possible de translater 'ago' ?

Answer (score 3):

If the date comes from an entity, you can just:

```
{{ entity.days }}
```

And in your entity just implement:

```
public function getDays()
{
    return $this->date->diff(new DateTime)->format('%a');
}
```