# Convert Javascript Date() to PHP Unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, php

I am recieving a date which uses javascript's date() function to generate a timestamp like so.

```
1451351941210
```

However my application is in php and I would like to convert that value to a unix timestamp like below

```
1451419198
```

I have tried dividing by 1000 but the function comes back as 18 years not 18 seconds.

Here is the code below

```
<?php

// Get javascript date() value
$date = 1451351941210;

// divide by 100 and round
$start_time = round($date/1000);

// run through function and echo
echo time_elapsed_string('@'. $start_time);

// Time function
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $string = array(
        'y' => 'year',
        'm' => 'month',
        'w' => 'week',
        'd' => 'day',
        'h' => 'hour',
        'i' => 'minute',
        's' => 'second',
    );
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }

    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}
```

Is there anything to directly convert the date() to a unix timestamp?

#### I want to use PHP, not javascript

The function I have used is taken from

[Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago/18602474#18602474)

Comment: You have a strange output from Javascript. It is quite distant from what I get now:  1451421138877. Could you show the exact JS code how you got it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try this on javascript ?

```
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
```

Comment: I want to use php.  The $date is returned from an external source in which they use js

Comment: Ok, did you try the same in php ? `floor($jsDate / 1000)`

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = (int) substr($date, 0, strlen($date) - 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert the current date and time to a UNIX timestamp do the following:

```
var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
```

getTime() returns milliseconds from the UNIX epoch, so divide it by 1000 to get the seconds representation. It is rounded using Math.round() to make it a whole number. The "ts" variable now has the UNIX timestamp for the current date and time relevent to the user's web browser.