# PHP date_diff() - find number of days and convert to hours

Tags: php, date, datetime

I wan't to find the date difference between to days and then convert it into hours

```
$date_diff = date_diff($latest_date, $oldest_date);
echo $date_diff->format(???);
```

I have tried to set format as `->format('h');` but didn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: So do you know how many hours there are in a day? (ignoring daylight savings shifts)

Comment: 24.. you mean to do the math way? I thought php had a build-in functionality to do this

Comment: look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/1689290)

Comment: It does have built-in functionality, but not for every conceivable variation; `$totalHours = $date_diff->days * 24 + $date_diff->h;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

**PHP**

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

echo 'Days : ' . $interval->days. '  ';
echo 'Hours : ' . $interval->days * 24;
```