# Date string to time format ('time' ago)

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to create a PHP function where I enter a `$date` variable with this format: 03/09/2016 - 12:02.

I created a function to turn this date / time variable into a string that says the `$date` variable was x days and hours ago.

Function:

```
$date = $r->date;

                function nicetime($date)
                {
                    if(empty($date)) {
                        return "Geen datum gevonden.";
                    }

                    $periods         = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
                    $lengths         = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

                    ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Berlin');
                    $now             = time('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $unix_date       = $date;

                       // check validity of date
                    if(empty($unix_date)) {    
                        return "Error.";
                    }

                    // is it future date or past date
                    if($now > $unix_date) {    
                        $difference     = $now - $unix_date;
                        $tense         = "ago";

                    } else {
                        $difference     = $unix_date - $now;
                        $tense         = "from now";
                    }

                    for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
                        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
                    }

                    $difference = round($difference);

                    if($difference != 1) {
                        $periods[$j].= "s";
                    }

                    return "$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";
                }

                $postdate = nicetime($date);
```

So I use `$date` to insert the date. And the outcome of `$postdate` is 47 years ago.
Does someone know what I'm doing wrong? Because I shouldn't get 47 years ago.

Comment: first I wonder why you don't use built in DateTime-Class, including DateInterval. Would be much easier to accomplish this.

Comment: Because I dont know how to use that

Comment: second: what is $date? A string containing "03/09/2016 - 12:02"? Or a timestamp?

Comment: $date is a string containing "03/09/2016 - 12:02"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago)

Answer (score 1):

So lets split your job to 3 steps:

Step 1: fork the time and the date. and then get then get the `long` time using the `strtotime()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Step 2: get the current `long` time from the `time()` function

Step 3: Now - Unix date

```
<?php
    $date = $r->date;

        function nicetime($date)
        {
            if(empty($date)) {
                return "Geen datum gevonden.";
            }
            $r1 = split('/', $date);
            $day = $r1[0]; 
            $month = $r1[1]; 
            $year = split(' ', $r1[2]);
            $year = $year[0];
            $r1 = split('-', $date);

            $periods         = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
            $lengths         = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

            ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Berlin');

            $now             = time();
            $unix_date       = strtotime($month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year.' '. $r1[1])."</br>";;

               // check validity of date
            if(empty($unix_date)) {    
                return "Error.";
            }

            // is it future date or past date
            if($now > $unix_date) {    
                $difference     = $now - $unix_date;
                $tense         = "ago";

            } else {
                $difference     = $unix_date - $now;
                $tense         = "from now";
            }

            for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
                $difference /= $lengths[$j];
            }

            $difference = round($difference);

            if($difference != 1) {
                $periods[$j].= "s";
            }

            return "$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";
        }

        $postdate = nicetime($date); // 2 days ago
        echo $postdate;
?>
```

Incidentally, You did a nice work.

**Update**: While using loop to this function make sure to enclose your function in a conditional block:

```
   if (!function_exists('nicetime')) {
    // ... proceed to declare your function
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its working now, but I am using this for Forum Posts to show the time its posted, so I'm using it in a While loop, but now it shows the time of the latest post, because it can't redeclare the function. Do you have a way to fix this?