# Read time using php

Tags: php, time

Hello i have a script and when she get time played(im using for game) she display to me the time like this: 1026.984375

I'm using this method `$playertime = ( is_numeric($p['time_online']) ) ? ceil($p['time_online']/60).' m' : $p['time_online'];`

But she display to me like this: 3052 m, i need to advence this script to display to me like: 50 H, 8 m, 6s.

Comment: I had no clue that PHP scripts can have genders.

Comment: You won't be able to get seconds. It looks like the finest your data will get is minutes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [DateInterval::createFromDateString](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php) (maybe in your case some rouding to seconds will be needed), then you will have a `DateInterval` object and then you could format it to [any format](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) you need.

Comment: Could You please specify the input string you are trying to convert?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with a time ago function thanks.