# Use of timestamp from database in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datetime

I am trying to run a counter from the time user is entered into database

I got this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/brkp1sa2/

which starts timer from 08/24/2012  while i need to start it from user date which i enter into database as timestamp at the time of signup

How I can do it as I fetch val from database like

```
<?php $timd = $db->fetchVal("select ts from users where id  = ?", $id); 
if (!empty($timd)) {
    $timdl = $timd->ts;
 }
```

Not know php pr jquery much so a code example answer can help me better

How to use this value into jquery so time start from given time stamp

Comment: what is `$check->ts` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago)

Comment: can I get an answer how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript timestamps are Javascript numbers representing [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in milliseconds.   MySQL uses [its `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to generate Unix timestamps (in seconds) from various kinds of date / time datatypes.

So, the query

```
    select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts) * 1000.0 AS ts from users where id  = ?
```

will generate a Javascript timestamp value.

Now, Javascript timestamps and Unix timestamps are, by design at least, in the UTC time zone. Depending on how your table's `ts` values were stored, your results may come out in local time.

Comment: Issue is not ts basic issue is how to use this string into jquery as `<?php $timd = $db->fetchVal("select ts from users where id  = ?", $id); ` outputs `$timd` as 2016-12-24 03:04:59  and if i succeed to put into jquery value  here `var timespan = countdown(new Date("2016-12-24 03:04:59"`   then jquery will start timer from that specific date and time