# Converting numerical date to text

Tags: php

I'm having some issues converting yyyy-mm-dd to text, and could use some pointers. This is what I currently have, but this obviously just outputs the numerical date:

```
$insert_date = $row['INSERT_DATE'];
$line_text = $row['LINE_TEXT'];
echo  "<tr height='10'><td>".$insert_date."</td>";
```

I'm unsure whether I should use the strtotime or date functions?

In other words, dates are in the MySQL DB as numerical entries, in the format, yyyy-mm-dd. Currently, the outputs matches this (eg, 2007-02-14). I'd prefer this to appear as February 14, 2007.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by numerical value? `yyyy-mm-dd` is text!

Comment: Or you might mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697

Comment: use a combination of date and strtotime like so `date('<format here>', strtotime($yourDateFromDB))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method of the `DateTime` class:

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$result = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

If `format` fails for some reason, it will return `FALSE`. In some applications, it might make sense to handle the failing case:

```
if ($result) {
  echo $result;
} else { // format failed
  echo "Unknown Time";
}
```