# How to declare date specific value for a function

Tags: php, mysql

**from this use example:**

```
echo time_elapsed_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35', true);
```

from this [Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago)

it must write exactly the date `'2013-05-01 00:22:35'`

now, i want to take date from this data in red box:
[image]
which i succeed if i write it like this:

```
<h4>di posisi sekarang:<br> <?php echo $row["tanggal"];  ?></h4><br>
```

but when i used it like this:

```
echo time_elapsed_string('<?php echo $row["tanggal"];  ?>', true);
```

it doesn't work, how do i get the data right?

Comment: "it doesn't work" - how? What result do you see?

Comment: Your argument fed in is a string of php code!

Comment: Try  `echo time_elapsed_string( $row["tanggal"], true);`

Comment: yes, sorry my silliness, my knowledge is extended a bit now. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to write PHP inside a PHP string. Just remove PHP tags and `echo`:

```
echo time_elapsed_string($row["tanggal"], true);
```

In your context:

```
<h4>di posisi sekarang:<br> 
    <?php echo time_elapsed_string($row["tanggal"], true);  ?>
</h4><br>
```

Comment: sorry my silliness, my knowledge is extended a bit now. :D

Comment: @borneo No worries :) Like you said, just knowledge to extend. Having issues helps to increase it.