# Determine time difference between now and stored date and time

Tags: php, mysql

in my sql table I save the date and time of a certain action, how can I print it via php on the contrary, or how long ago did it take place?

for example

```
|date                |
|05-28-2020 17:12:05 |
```

and at 17:30:05 it will be written on my php page
"18 minutes ago"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Load the date from the database using a `mysqli_query` and store the result in `$original_date`.
2. Create a date object from the string in the database.

```php
$old_date = new DateTime($original_date);
```

3. Get the current date in the same format and store it in another variable.

```php
$current_date = new DateTime(date("m-d-Y H:m:s"));
```

4. Get the difference between the two dates.

```php
$difference = $old_date->diff($current_date);
```

5. Convert the difference to minutes and display message.

```php
echo($difference->m . "minutes ago");
```

Here is the full code for you to use:

```php
# Get database value and store in $original_date

$old_date = new DateTime($original_date);
$current_date = new DateTime(date("m-d-Y H:m:s"));
$difference = $old_date->diff($current_date);

echo($difference->m . "minutes ago");
```