# how do i use mentioned issue in PHP timedate ago

Tags: php

so hello i am trying to use this most used php script linked here
[Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago)
but i cannot get it working, i thought i would fill variable with $datetime with the date i want to differente with
i am inputting date with this format "1614084957" but yet i get error

> **Error: Uncaught Error: Class 'datetime' not found in**

i dont know what wrong its included the function is above the desired echo

```
            function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
                $now = new DateTime;
                $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
                $diff = $now->diff($ago);
            
                $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
                $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;
            
                $string = array(
                    'y' => 'year',
                    'm' => 'month',
                    'w' => 'week',
                    'd' => 'day',
                    'h' => 'hour',
                    'i' => 'minute',
                    's' => 'second',
                );
                foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
                    if ($diff->$k) {
                        $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
                    } else {
                        unset($string[$k]);
                    }
                }
            
                if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
                return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
            }


if ($page->id == 1) {
    $kat = $pages->get('/kategorie/');
    include('chunks/hry.php');
}
```

in hry.php i jsut have som foreach and ifs
i have foreach for each a link to game a i wanted to use this function to determine when this game was created,

Comment: I'm just guessing ( because you didn't provide the framework used ) that you are using namespaces in your code. If yes, then you need to use fully qualified class name `$now = new \DateTime;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `\` before your class name

```
$now = new \DateTime;
$ago = new \DateTime($datetime);
```

Comment: hello so i hope i understand correctly so i had to add these in the function i copied ? if so i did that but now i got different error now the function starts like  this
`function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
 $now = new \DateTime;
 $ago = new \DateTime($datetime);
 $diff = $now->diff($ago);`
and then i have
`$ago = $page->created;
echo time_elapsed_string($ago);`
now echo $ago outputs date in this format **1614084957**
which is good i hope and lastly i get this error
Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (1614084957) at position 7 (9):

Comment: nvm fixed it by adding 
`echo time_elapsed_string('@'.$ago);`