# How to echo (time ago) by specific time zone in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to get time ago by `date("Y-m-d h:i:s");` so the output is `2021-07-03 04:52:12` that's good.

And I'm using this function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/10297861) to get time ago like `1 minute ago`

When i use the this [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/10297861) to get time ago it's works fine, But i need the time ago in this TimeZone `Asia\Amman`

PHP code to echo current date in `Asia\Amman`

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Amman');
$updated_at = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
echo $updated_at;
```

Output :

`2021-07-03 04:52:12`

In time ago:

`10 hours ago`

But it's should be:

`2 seconds ago` or `1 seconds ago`

The function I use:

```
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $string = array(
        'y' => 'year',
        'm' => 'month',
        'w' => 'week',
        'd' => 'day',
        'h' => 'hour',
        'i' => 'minute',
        's' => 'second',
    );
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }

    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: When are you calling `time_elapsed_string()`? If you're doing it *before* the call to `date_default_timezone_set()` then that may cause problems. Make sure you're calling `date_default_timezone_set()` first.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same result: `10 hours ago`

Comment: Well, 1 minute ago is 1 minute ago, regardless the timezone :)

Comment: Yes!, But how i can echo that's , Can you explain ?

Comment: You could try `$now = new DateTime; $now->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Asia\Amman')); $ago = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone('Asia\Amman'));`

Comment: Thanks!, I think it's work fine but the `Asia\Amman` it's not supported I think, and the output echo this error: `Uncaught Exception: DateTimeZone: :__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone (Asia\Amman)`

Comment: Try it with a forward slash - Asia/Amman https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php

Comment: Thanks @Ameer !, I just added `$now->sub(new DateInterval("PT4H0M1S"));` to your edit and it's solve my problem, So I will edit my question to add the current code for that, Thanks a lot to all!

Comment: @AmeerDesign: Don't edit the question, add an answer explaining your solution and put the current code for that in there. You can then later mark the question as answered (and everytime you remember you need to do something similar, you can find your answer here).

Comment: @hakre: Thanks. I will do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer is:**

@Ameer in the comments has edit this:

```
$now = new DateTime;
$ago = new DateTime($datetime);
```

To this:

```
$now = new DateTime; 
$now->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Asia\Amman')); 
$ago = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone('Asia\Amman'));
```

But it's doesn't work because `Asia\Amman` it's not supported in the [list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) that `DateTimeZone` support so i found this [website](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/jordan/amman) show the code of `Asia\Amman` `EEST`

So the result changes from `10 hours ago` to `5 hours ago` that's good news

But it's not solve the problem yet

So now I need `-5 hours` from `5 hours ago`

I found this `sub(new DateInterval("PT4H0M1S"))`

The `PT4H` means `4 hours`

The `0M` means `0 minutes`

The `1S` means `1 seconds`

So the `sub` means `-` and `add` means `+` to `DateTime`

Anddd the final code of the function is:

```
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime; 
    $now->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('EST')); 
    $now->sub(new DateInterval("PT4H0M1S"));
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone('EST')); 
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $string = array(
        'y' => 'year',
        'm' => 'month',
        'w' => 'week',
        'd' => 'day',
        'h' => 'hour',
        'i' => 'minute',
        's' => 'second',
    );
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }

    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}
```

And don't forgot to added `date_default_timezone_set()` after the `date` time with your specific `TimeZone` in my case `Asia\Amman`

have a nice coding!