# 5 min ago in php

Tags: php, date

I have stored a date in database as "**15-10-2012**",while showing in the front end when the date is not older than one day.I need to show 2 min age , 5 hours ago etc.

how can i achieve this?
thanks in advance.

**Input**

```
15-10-2012
```

**Output**

```
"2 days ago"
```

Comment: [calculating and showing a date as 'secs ago', 'mins ago', 'hours ago' etc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2452010)

Comment: [Calculate time difference between two dates, and present the answer like "2 days 3 hours ago"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/432398)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate time difference between two dates, and present the answer like "2 days 3 hours ago"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432398/calculate-time-difference-between-two-dates-and-present-the-answer-like-2-days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this article http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/mysql-selecting-timestamp-from-database-now-minute-t82112.html

And take a look at MYSQL's INTERVAL
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

I think this will help you:
`WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_date) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)`

Answer (score 0):

First calculate a unix timestamp from the date, then substract from current time and turn the difference in minutes/hours/days.

```
list($day,$month,$year) = explode('-', $date);
$time = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year);
$now = time();
$difference = $now - $time;
$minutes = intval($difference / 60);

$hours = intval($minutes / 60 ); 

if ($hours > 24) {
   $days = intval($hours / 24);
}
```

Comment: But this won't do what he wants, will it?

Answer (score 0):

(assuming day-month-year)

2 minutes ago:

echo date('j-n-Y', strtotime('15-10-2012') - 120);

Or:

echo date('j-n-Y', strtotime('15-10-2012 -2 minutes'));

Really your starting date should be a timestamp down to the second. If storing just the day/month/year then you'd need to assume each date starts at 00:01